# Public path lists all files in view

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am embedding a pdf file in my view, like this

```
<embed src = "{{$pdfUrl.$accessProfileDet->server_folder}}" width="100%" height="600px" type="application/pdf">
```

It works fine if the variable `$accessProfileDet->server_folder` has value. `$pdfUrl` is my public path. If `$accessProfileDet->server_folder` is null, view lists all files in the public folder. Please suggest any easy solution for this. Since my images like website logo, banner etc are in public folder, I don't like to prefer a special route to solve this, Is there any alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
Just place a blank html file named 'index.html' in your public folder. This will solve the issue. Also you can avoid embedding the code by an if condition like this,
@if($accessProfileDet->server_folder != '')
    <embed src="{{$pdfUrl.$accessProfileDet->server_folder}}" width="100%" height="600px" type="application/pdf">
@else
    <div class="no-pdf">No data available!</div>
@endif
```